# iOS Swift - push notification: Save all Remote-Notifications in a Database (also while App is terminated)

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I would like to save all received notifications in a database.

This works if someone clicks on the notification or the notification is received while the app is in the foreground.

**But the challenge is to save the notification while the app is terminated (loud push).**

After the launch of the terminated app the function **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** is called but the launchOptions aways is **nil** so I can't handle push notifications.

Does anybody have any idea to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The app doesn't get notified when a push arrives without the user interacting with it. That's a privacy feature.

Comment: Thank´s for respond. Is there a way around this?

Comment: You could keep track of the sent (and not „received“) notifications in the backend and ask it when you launch the app. That‘s the easiest way I suppose :)

Comment: Good to know ;). If a User clears a notification, is there a way to run code?

Comment: I guess I have to withdraw my first claim. You may use that mechanism to track the received push notifications: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/modifying_content_in_newly_delivered_notifications

Comment: As far as I know there is no way tho to know if a user cleared the notifications

Comment: Thanks a lot for this link. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Goergisn.

The solution to my problem:

1. Create an **UNNotificationServiceExtension** (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/modifying_content_in_newly_delivered_notifications or https://medium.com/gits-apps-insight/processing-notification-data-using-notification-service-extension-6a2b5ea2da17)
2. Create an **App Group**
3. Save data from Notification Service to App Group
4. Create a function in the ViewController to transfer the data from the App Group into a sql-database

Comment: this is not working when notification received without image.